# Symfony2 create form type with inheritance property

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create a form type with a inherited property, I have one entity (Candidate) that have two attributes (String dni and User user).

Is it possible to add a property from user (user.username) into a candidate form?
I want something like this:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('dni', null, array_merge(array(
            'label' => 'form.dni',
            'translation_domain' => 'DroidersCandidateBundle',
        ), $this->mergeOptions))
        ->add('username', null, array_merge(array(
            'label' => 'form.username',
            'translation_domain' => 'SonataUserBundle'
        ), $this->mergeOptions))
        ;
    }
```

Comment: What you will want to do is to create a UserFormType that deals with username and embed it in your main form.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem with embeded form, but I'm looking something like the answer from FyodorX, but that answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is that the `Entity` bound to the form doesn't have the property `username`. It's its property `user` who does.

Thus, you need to tell the `Form` how to access the right property. This is achieved by using the `property_path` option. [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path)'s the documentation for it.

You would do something like this in your filter's Type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('dni', null, array_merge(array(
        'label' => 'form.dni',
        'translation_domain' => 'DroidersCandidateBundle',
    ), $this->mergeOptions))
    ->add('username', null, array_merge(array(
        'label' => 'form.username',
        'property_path' => 'user.username',
        'translation_domain' => 'SonataUserBundle'
    ), $this->mergeOptions))
    ;
}
```

The `property_path` option is very powerful. It will accept any path that the `PropertyAccess` component does. Read its documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking something like that but I try this and doesn't work for me, this is the error: Expected argument of type "object or array", "NULL" given

Comment: Could you post the complete exception message?

Comment: This is the complete exception message:

Expected argument of type "object or array", "NULL" given
500 Internal Server Error - UnexpectedTypeException

Comment: Probably means that your candidate object has no user object associated with it.

Comment: Yes, that's probably it. If you are unable to find the problem post another question and we'll try to help you.

Comment: I posted another question [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747403/symfony2-create-form-type-with-inheritance-property-without-a-embeded-form